# Múltiplos FXML dentro da mesma cena JavaFX

Tags: javafx, view, fxml

Tenho a seguinte cena no JavaFX:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero que, ao usuário clicar nos botões "Clientes", "Produtos" ou "Fornecedores", abra o FXML correspondente a cada um desses botões que eu irei criar em outros arquivos separados, abaixo dos botões, como se fosse um iframe:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso fazer isso?

Obrigado.

Comment: Faltou o código do seu programa até agora, só as imagens não ajudam a ter uma ideia do que você está fazendo.

Comment: Eu sou leigo ainda. Eu quero saber o que eu preciso fazer para conseguir criar "múltiplos layouts" na mesma scene para eu pesquisar.